# Multiple integral using Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

How is it possible for args to be updated with no assignment in the integrate function of _NQuad? Can someone please explain what is going on with this code?

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from functools import partial

class _RangeFunc:
    def __init__(self, range_):
        self.range_ = range_

    def __call__(self, *args):
        """Return stored value.

        *args needed because range_ can be float or func, and is called with
        variable number of parameters.
        """
        return self.range_

class _OptFunc:
    def __init__(self, opt):
        self.opt = opt

    def __call__(self, *args):
        """Return stored dict."""
        return self.opt


class _NQuad:
    
    def __init__(self, func, ranges, opts, full_output):
        self.loop = 0
        self.abserr = 0
        self.func = func
        self.ranges = ranges
        self.opts = opts
        self.maxdepth = len(ranges)
        self.full_output = full_output
        if self.full_output:
            self.out_dict = {'neval': 0}

    def integrate(self, *args, **kwargs):
        depth = kwargs.pop('depth', 0)
        if kwargs:
            raise ValueError('unexpected kwargs')

        # Get the integration range and options for this depth.
        ind = -(depth + 1)
        fn_range = self.ranges[ind]
        low, high = fn_range(*args)
        fn_opt = self.opts[ind]
        opt = dict(fn_opt(*args))

        if 'points' in opt:
            opt['points'] = [x for x in opt['points'] if low <= x <= high]
        if depth + 1 == self.maxdepth:
            f = self.func
        else:
            f = partial(self.integrate, depth=depth+1)
        quad_r = quad(f, low, high, args=args, full_output=self.full_output,**opt)
        print(f'loop: {self.loop}; args: {args}; quad_r: {quad_r}')
        self.loop += 1
        value = quad_r[0]
        abserr = quad_r[1]
        if self.full_output:
            infodict = quad_r[2]
            # The 'neval' parameter in full_output returns the total
            # number of times the integrand function was evaluated.
            # Therefore, only the innermost integration loop counts.
            if depth + 1 == self.maxdepth:
                self.out_dict['neval'] += infodict['neval']
        self.abserr = max(self.abserr, abserr)
        if depth > 0:
            return value
        else:
            # Final result of N-D integration with error
            if self.full_output:
                return value, self.abserr, self.out_dict
            else:
                return value, self.abserr



def nquad(func, ranges, args=None, opts=None, full_output=False):

    depth = len(ranges)
    ranges = [rng if callable(rng) else _RangeFunc(rng) for rng in ranges]
    if args is None:
        args = ()
    if opts is None:
        opts = [dict([])] * depth

    if isinstance(opts, dict):
        opts = [_OptFunc(opts)] * depth
    else:
        opts = [opt if callable(opt) else _OptFunc(opt) for opt in opts]
    return _NQuad(func, ranges, opts, full_output).integrate(*args)


def func(x, y):
    return x*y**2

ranges = [[0, 2], [0, 1]]
opts = {"epsabs": 1.49e-8, "epsrel": 1.49e-8}
args = ()
full_output = False

result = nquad(func=func, ranges=ranges, args=args, opts=opts, full_output=False)
result
```

The args parameter in the integrate method of _NQuad is a variable-length argument list which is passed to the quad function as args=args. In each loop of _NQuad, the *args syntax is used to unpack the args tuple into separate arguments, which are then used in various calculations.

So, while there is no explicit assignment to args within the integrate method, the contents of args are effectively being updated with each iteration of the loop, as the values of the unpacked arguments change.

In summary, the args parameter is being passed around and unpacked as needed, and its contents are being updated implicitly through the manipulation of the unpacked arguments.

Comment: The `quad` source is readable via the `[source]` link on the docs.  Essentially it calls the `func` with `func(x, *args)`.  It selects `x` values, but passes `args` through untouched.  I haven't studied your code, but can well imagine a `func` that changes `args` values when called.  A tuple is immutable, but its contents may be mutable lists or arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example of function that modifies its `args` parameter.  It doesn't do anything significant, but shows how that parameter can be changed. There's a change each time the function is called, but otherwise `quad` doesn't do anything with it.

```
In [222]: from scipy.integrate import quad

In [223]: def fun(x,*args):
     ...:     args[0].append('foobar')
     ...:     return x**2
     ...:     

In [224]: alist=[]; quad(fun, 0, 1, args=(alist,))
Out[224]: (0.33333333333333337, 3.700743415417189e-15)

In [225]: alist
Out[225]: 
['foobar',
 'foobar',
 'foobar',
 'foobar',
 'foobar',
 'foobar',
 'foobar',
  ...
 'foobar']
```